# How to Create a Separate Table for Each Result/Record set Returned by a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I found an extremely helpful stored procedure (http://goo.gl/exB1VH) by Sorna Kumar Muthuraj on the web that allowed me to search across all the tables in my SQL database.  What gets returned in most cases are multiple record sets.  What I would like to do is modify my SP as described in ["How do I grab multiple outputs from a stored procedure into temp table"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792412/how-do-i-grab-multiple-outputs-from-a-stored-procedure-into-temp-table) (and not use the CLR )   so each record set gets written to its own table.  I read the answer to this stackoverflow question and because I have a `WHILE` statement, I can’t figure out how create a separate table or temp table for each record set each time it loops through the statement.  Is it not possible in this case to modify the SP?  Will I have to resort to using the CLR method?

```
EXEC spSQL_SearchDatabase @Tablenames = '',@SearchStr  = '%testing 123%'
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSQL_SearchDatabase
 @Tablenames VARCHAR(500)
,@SearchStr NVARCHAR(60)
,@GenerateSQLOnly Bit = 0
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @MatchFound BIT 

    SELECT @MatchFound = 0

DECLARE @CheckTableNames Table
(
Tablename sysname
)

DECLARE @SQLTbl TABLE
(
 Tablename      SYSNAME
,WHEREClause    VARCHAR(MAX)
,SQLStatement   VARCHAR(MAX)
,Execstatus     BIT 
)

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tmpTblname sysname
DECLARE @ErrMsg VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(50)

IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@Tablenames)) IN ('' ,'%')
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @CheckTableNames
    SELECT Name
      FROM sys.tables
END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@Tablenames,',',''' UNION SELECT ''') + ''''

    INSERT INTO @CheckTableNames
    EXEC(@sql)

END

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @CheckTableNames) 
BEGIN 

    SELECT @ErrMsg = 'No tables are found in this database ' + DB_NAME() + ' for the specified filter' 
    PRINT @ErrMsg 
    RETURN 
END  

INSERT INTO @SQLTbl(Tablename, WHEREClause)
SELECT QUOTENAME(SCh.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ST.NAME),
        (
            SELECT '[' + SC.name + ']' + ' LIKE ''' + @SearchStr + ''' OR ' + CHAR(10)
              FROM SYS.columns SC
              JOIN SYS.types STy
                ON STy.system_type_id = SC.system_type_id
               AND STy.user_type_id =SC.user_type_id
             WHERE STY.name in ('varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar')
               AND SC.object_id = ST.object_id
             ORDER BY SC.name
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
  FROM  SYS.tables ST
  JOIN @CheckTableNames chktbls
            ON chktbls.Tablename = ST.name 
  JOIN SYS.schemas SCh
    ON ST.schema_id = SCh.schema_id
 WHERE ST.name <> 'SearchTMP'
  GROUP BY ST.object_id, QUOTENAME(SCh.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ST.NAME) ;

  UPDATE @SQLTbl 
     SET SQLStatement = 'SELECT * INTO SearchTMP FROM ' + Tablename + ' WHERE ' + substring(WHEREClause,1,len(WHEREClause)-5) 

  DELETE FROM @SQLTbl
   WHERE WHEREClause IS NULL


WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SQLTbl WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @tmpTblname = Tablename , @sql = SQLStatement
    FROM @SQLTbl 
    WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0

    IF @GenerateSQLOnly = 0
        BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID('SearchTMP','U') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE SearchTMP

        EXEC (@sql)

        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SearchTMP)
            BEGIN
                SELECT  Tablename=@tmpTblname, * FROM SearchTMP
                SELECT @MatchFound = 1
            END
        END
     ELSE
     BEGIN
         PRINT REPLICATE('-',100)
         PRINT @tmpTblname
         PRINT REPLICATE('-',100)
         PRINT replace(@sql,'INTO SearchTMP','')

     END

     UPDATE @SQLTbl
        SET Execstatus = 1
      WHERE Tablename = @tmpTblname

END

IF @MatchFound = 0  
BEGIN 
    SELECT @ErrMsg = 'No Matches are found in this database ' + DB_NAME() + ' for the specified filter' 
    PRINT @ErrMsg 
    RETURN 
END 

SET NOCOUNT OFF
go
```

This is where I tried modifying my stored procedure within the `WHILE` statement with an `INTO` clause:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SearchTMP)
  BEGIN
    SELECT Tablename=@tmpTblname, * INTO ResultsTMP FROM SearchTMP
    SELECT @MatchFound = 1
  END
```

Of course all it does is return an error

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Tablename' in table 'ResultsTmP' is specified more than once

because the table already exists.

Thoughts?

Comment: This error `Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Tablename' in table 'ResultsTmP' is specified more than once` is because you are selecting Tablename and all fields (*) - which contains Tablename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understnad your question. It seams quite obvious that the problem is that you are storing all results to the same table.

I did a few tweeks that might solve your problem.

I was not overly found of that the procedure used "normal" tabeles as temp tables.

1. You cannot run this i database where you are not owner (or has right to create tables).
2. You are filling up the transaction log with non-production data.

It now creates temp table in a way you want (called ##SearchResult_xxxxxx) where xxxx is the table name.

```
create PROCEDURE spSQL_SearchDatabase
     @Tablenames VARCHAR(500)
    ,@SearchStr NVARCHAR(60)
    ,@GenerateSQLOnly Bit = 0
    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        DECLARE @MatchFound BIT 

        SELECT @MatchFound = 0

    DECLARE @CheckTableNames Table
    (
    Tablename sysname
    )

    DECLARE @SQLTbl TABLE
    (
     Tablename      SYSNAME
    ,WHEREClause    VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,SQLStatement   VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,Execstatus     BIT 
    )

    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @outputTableName sysname
    DECLARE @tmpTblname sysname
    DECLARE @ErrMsg VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @test VARCHAR(50)

    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@Tablenames)) IN ('' ,'%')
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @CheckTableNames
        SELECT Name
          FROM sys.tables
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@Tablenames,',',''' UNION SELECT ''') + ''''

        INSERT INTO @CheckTableNames
        EXEC(@sql)

    END

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @CheckTableNames) 
    BEGIN 

        SELECT @ErrMsg = 'No tables are found in this database ' + DB_NAME() + ' for the specified filter' 
        PRINT @ErrMsg 
        RETURN 
    END  

    INSERT INTO @SQLTbl(Tablename, WHEREClause)
    SELECT QUOTENAME(SCh.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ST.NAME),
            (
                SELECT '[' + SC.name + ']' + ' LIKE ''' + @SearchStr + ''' OR ' + CHAR(10)
                  FROM SYS.columns SC
                  JOIN SYS.types STy
                    ON STy.system_type_id = SC.system_type_id
                   AND STy.user_type_id =SC.user_type_id
                 WHERE STY.name in ('varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar')
                   AND SC.object_id = ST.object_id
                 ORDER BY SC.name
                FOR XML PATH('')
            )
      FROM  SYS.tables ST
      JOIN @CheckTableNames chktbls
                ON chktbls.Tablename = ST.name 
      JOIN SYS.schemas SCh
        ON ST.schema_id = SCh.schema_id
     WHERE ST.name  'SearchTMP'
      GROUP BY ST.object_id, QUOTENAME(SCh.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ST.NAME) ;

      UPDATE @SQLTbl 
         SET SQLStatement = 'SELECT * INTO ##SearchTMP FROM ' + Tablename + ' WHERE ' + substring(WHEREClause,1,len(WHEREClause)-5) 

      DELETE FROM @SQLTbl
       WHERE WHEREClause IS NULL


    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SQLTbl WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0)
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1 @tmpTblname = Tablename , @sql = SQLStatement
        FROM @SQLTbl 
        WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0

        IF @GenerateSQLOnly = 0
            BEGIN
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##SearchTMP','U') IS NOT NULL
                DROP TABLE ##SearchTMP

            EXEC (@sql)

            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ##SearchTMP)
                BEGIN
                    set @outputTableName = '[##SearchResult_'+ 
                        replace(replace(@tmpTblname,'[',''),']','') +']'
                    print 'Created ' + @outputTableName
                    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..'+@outputTableName,'U') IS NOT NULL
                        exec ('DROP TABLE tempdb.'+@outputTableName)
                    exec ('SELECT  Tablename='''+@tmpTblname+''', * into ' +@outputTableName + ' FROM ##SearchTMP')

                    SELECT @MatchFound = 1
                END
            END
         ELSE
         BEGIN
             PRINT REPLICATE('-',100)
             PRINT @tmpTblname
             PRINT REPLICATE('-',100)
             PRINT replace(@sql,'INTO ##SearchTMP','')

         END

         UPDATE @SQLTbl
            SET Execstatus = 1
          WHERE Tablename = @tmpTblname

    END

    IF @MatchFound = 0  
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @ErrMsg = 'No Matches are found in this database ' + DB_NAME() + ' for the specified filter' 
        PRINT @ErrMsg 
        RETURN 
    END 

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##SearchTMP','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE ##SearchTMP

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    go
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Maybe I should have worded my initial question differently, but I knew the way the code was written it was storing the results into the same table, my question was how to rewrite it so I could store each result into its own table which you answered with your tweek.  Thanks! I also prefer to use a normal table instead of a global temp table.

Comment: Any time :-) And if you don´t use temp tables it is up to you, just be aware of the drawbacks.